# Postgresql. Generate sets of random integers

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, random

With this command I can generate 16384 random integers between 1 AND 200,000.

```
SELECT generate_series (1,16384),(random()*200000)::int AS id
```

I want to generate 10 sets of such integers. Each set must have an integer identifier, something like that:

> 1 | 135
>
> 1 | 1023
>
> ... end of first set of 16384 random numbers
>
> 2 | 15672
>
> 2 | 258732
>
> ... end of second set of 16384 random numbers

Is this possible with an SQL command, or should I write a function for that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Would this be what you want?

```
SELECT 
   n, generate_series (1,16384), (random()*200000)::int AS id 
FROM  
   generate_series (1,10) AS x(n) ;
```

or the similar:

```
SELECT 
    n, i, (random()*200000)::int AS id 
FROM  
    generate_series (1,10) AS x(n) 
  CROSS JOIN
    generate_series (1,16384) AS y(i) ;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like this:

```
SELECT ((generate_series-1)/16384)::int+1 as series, (random()*200000)::int as rand
    from generate_series(1,10*16384);
```

This does the sampling with replacement.  If it needs to be done without replacement, that is quite a bit hard.